# Javascript virtual environment?

Tags: javascript

I found 2 javascript virtual envirenments: envjs and jsdom, but I was wondering if there aren't others one out there. If so, please share. (and yes I google it before I ask the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS is a pretty good option. Its essentially a headless version of Webkit.

http://www.phantomjs.org/

Comment: envJs is used to simulate the behavior before rendering a  webpage. Can PhantomJs be used to simulate such behavior too ?

Comment: envjs allows you to run a testsuite of javascript tests from the commandline (outside of a browser) - phantomjs does the same thing except that it replicates the browser environment of Webkit 100% because its using Webkit without a GUI. Both are great projects but I'm a bigger fan of running tests within an actual browser environment (as opposed to a simulated environ like envjs).